# Was unprecedented or is unprecedented?

Tags: word-choice

I am writing about the GME short squeeze that happened in January 2021.

At some point, I want to say that short squeezes are nothing new in finance, but the way it was triggered was not seen before.

What would be the correct way to say this?

> The way it was triggered was unprecedented.

or

> The way it was triggered is unprecedented.

The reason I am asking, is that it is of course still unprecedented, as something that was once unprecedented can not become 'un-unprecedented', right? Using 'was' seems like the right way to go as that really emphasizes that it was unprecedented back than, but I just wanted to be sure if it would be allowed to use it that way.

Comment: Doesn't the first occurence of an event become the precedent for subsequent events of the same type? So this type of trigger ceased to be unprecedented in January 2021.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. So it would be the was option then, as it is no longer unprecedented?

Comment: The historic present is often available ('Blériot's 1909 flight across the Channel is unprecedented.') And an event that _was_ unprecedented _remains_ the first ever. But although your second variant is grammatical and not illogical, using different tenses in such close proximity sounds awkward.

Comment: Also, you didn't ask for general writing advice and we don't cover it here... *but if we did*... I might suggest that "unprecedented" has been so heavily used in the last couple of years that it's become its own hot-topic cliché, and is often used with apology or comment, so it might be smart to reword.

Comment: Thanks @AndyBonner, I think you are right in that, so I am indeed considering rewording.

Comment: Thanks @EdwinAshworth, that answers my question exactly. Is there any way I can mark this question as answered even though I have not received an official answer outside the comments? (I'm new here)

Comment: I didn't give an 'answer' as it's largely a duplicate. I've found what I consider the best fit, though I'd use the present with 'He didn't know where New Jersey is'! Can't you close this question?